# Динамический роутер с проверкой через сервис

Tags: javascript, angularjs, route, angular-routing, router

есть два адреса в роутере:

```
when('/:userName', {
    resolve: { //сюда прилетают данные только по юзеру
        userdata: resolves.userdata
    },
    templateUrl: '/partials/userPage.html',
    controller: 'userCtrl'
}).
when('/magazine/:magazineName', {
    resolve: { //сюда прилетают данные по юзеру и журналу
        magazine: resolves.magazine, 
        userdata: resolves.userdata 
    },
    templateUrl: '/partials/magazine.html',
    controller: 'magazineCtrl'
    controllerAs: 'vm',
})
```

необходимо совместить их в один

```
when('/:objName', {
    resolve: {
        magazine: resolves.magazine,
        userdata: resolves.userdata
    },
    templateUrl: '/partials/magazine(userPage).html',
    controller: 'magazineCtrl(userCtrl)'
})
```

и использовать проверку параметра через сервис, так чтобы в зависимости от ответа сервиса общий роут динамически менялся

```
.service('userOrMagazine', ['$route', '$q', 'tools', function($route, $q, tools) {
    var params = $route.current.params,
        objName= params.objName? params.objName: null,
        q = $q.defer();
    if (!objName) q.reject();
    tools.data.get(api.RESOLVE.format(objName)).then(function(data) {
        // data.type равен 'users или 'magazines'

        return q.resolve(data.type);
    });
    return q.promise;
}]);
```

есть мысли как это реализовать?

Comment: что имеется ввиду под _общим роутом_ и как он должен меняться?

Comment: в параметр objName летит текст, текст проходит через сервис, и в зависимости от того что отдаст сервис ('users' или 'magazines') использовать необходимые контролеры и шаблоны

Comment: со стандартным роутером невозможно _выбрать_ контроллер в зависимости от чего-то на уровне `controller: 'magazineCtrl(userCtrl)'`